# Ionic navCtrl.setPages not working in app.component.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my app.component.ts file I have a code that sends the user to a different page if he taps on a FCM notification
The code is something like this:

```
this.fcm.listenToNotifications().subscribe(async(notification) => {             
    if (notification.tap) {
        const pages = [
            {page: Page1},
            {page: Page1Subpage, params: {...}}
        ];
    this.navCtrl.setPages(pages);
    this.navCtrl.parent.select(1);
}
```

When I execute the notification, I see the following error in my Xcode editor:

```
2019-01-17 16:55:13.230990+0200 Adservio[2103:800067] ERROR: Unhandled Promise rejection: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.navCtrl.setPages') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.navCtrl.setPages') http://localhost:8080/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9301607C-7904-4404-B00D-FE8D9E7EED17/Adservio.app/www/build/main.js:1:1380986
```

Does anybody have any idea why ?

Comment: remove `async`, subscribe is already handling that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is related [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component) :

> What if you want to control navigation from **your root app component**?
>   You **can't** inject **NavController** because any components that are
>   navigation controllers are children of the root component so they
>   aren't available to be injected.

But you can use **Nav**

```
import { Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

//....

export class MyApp {

@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

//...

//And inside your function 

//..

this.nav.push('Page1');

//..
```

Answer (score 0):

In your root component you should use Nav and not NavController. See more here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component

> You can't inject NavController because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the root component so they aren't available to be injected.

Also check reference app implementation:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/v3/src/app/app.component.ts